# How to call a BroadcastReceiver method to another method?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to call the BroadcastReceiver method to execute the code while the user isn't using the Application but I don't know how can I make that happen.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
         // this method is what I want to call
    }

    public static void Toast(Context context, Intent intent){
        // this is where I want to call the BroadcastReceiver
    }
}
```

I already received and send SMS by the used of BroadcastReceiver as what my application should be works.
The only thing that I want to solved now is how can I execute the code in the MainActivity while my application is not using by the user? Because I figured out that the BroadcastReceiver which is at the other activity is the only running when the application is not using.
In my application, I used SharedPreferences to saved and update the application. Like if the Application receive "ON" the on button will show and the off button will hide and otherwise. Which is already works well now.
Awhile ago, I try to call a toast() method from MainActivity.java to SMSReceiver.java(which is only running background includes BroadcastReceiver) to see if the method that I called will executed which I include toast.maketext() in the toast() method. And yes it executed because the toast message appear.

Now, I thought if I only put the code with the SharedPreferences that are executed when the application is using will put on that toast() method, it will also executed as what the toast() method run awhile ago and my problem will be solved. But then, I don't know how can I make that happen because I cannot call the method wherein the code is in there. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an action that the broadcast should respond to:

`public static final String ACTION_NAME = "com.application.ACTION";`

To send an `Intent` for a listener to react to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NAME);
intent.putExtra(OPTIONAL_EXTRA_KEY, "your optional extra value");
yourContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In order to listen to a Broadcast you need to define a `Receiver` object.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // React to the broadcast.
    }
};
```

Now you have to register this BroadcastReceiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME);
yourActivity.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

And to unregister:

```
yourActivity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

I usually register and unregister in onResume and onPause but your application might require it in different places.

Comment: I already received and send SMS. My only problem now is how can I put the method to another method. I try to put static to BroadcastReceiver but some of the code underlined by red I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Other way than perspective is what I've done to solved my problem. In static method, you cannot call a BroadcastReceiver because BroadcastReceiver method was not a static method and you cannot put the word static on it like what my

```
public static void(Context context, Intent intent){

}
```

Static is for static and non-static is for non-static.

Because I just want to call the SharedPreferences to saved data while the Application is not using, I just put SharedPreferences: initialization of SharedPreferences, editing and saving on my static method. And the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some code when user is not using your app, you have to use services. I realy advise you to use IntentService